# Making Enum work

Tags: c++

In `player.h` I have `enum race {Living, Dead, Nature,None};`

In `player.cpp` I have

```
race myRace;
    void Player::addPlayer(int x)
 {
    cout<<"added player"<<x<<endl;
    this->karma=0;
    this->myTurn=false;
    myRace=race(4);

 }
```

So this should , when a player is created make myRace = None.

Now in `Main.cpp` I want to check a players race, how would i do this?
I tried `if (player[x].myRace=None)` but of course that wont work..

Comment: Does main.cpp include player.h ?

Comment: What does that mean "of course that wont work" ?

Comment: yes the linking between classes is correct when i do player[x].  all other items show up just not myRace.... well if it worked, i would not of made post :D

Comment: this is a really strange addplayer method.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use integers to refer to the values of an `enum`. Use the proper names: `myRace = None;`. _If_ you use integers, make sure you use them correctly. If I am not mistaken, `None` corresponds to 3, not 4.

Comment: Using raw integers defeats the point of having the `enum`.  Also, when you try to do your check, did you actually use `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: Is `myRace` really a *global* variable, and not a member of `Player`?

Comment: BTW, you might want to put `None` at the beginning of your enum, because then the implicit conversion to `bool` will convert `None`to false and all other values to `true`, which makes sense for your enum. As is, it will convert `Living` to `false` and all other values (including `None`) to true, which likely doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Style suggestion: Make your class members distinct by giving them a prefix such as "m_", e.g. "m_myRace", so that you don't run into problems where you can't tell which is a class member and which is a local variable or function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums should work the way you describe. Unfortunately you only provided modified, unrunnable code and no compiler errors or other output. However, the following code should show you how to use enums: ([Live demo](http://ideone.com/GMCCjm))

```
#include <iostream>

enum Race { None, Living, Dead, Nature}; // always put invalid as the 0 entry.

class Player
{
      uint32_t m_karma;
      bool     m_myTurn;
      Race     m_myRace;

public:
    void addPlayer(int x_)
    {
        std::cout << "added player " << x_ << std::endl;
        m_karma = 0;
        m_myTurn = false;
        m_myRace = None;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Player fred;
    fred.addPlayer(1);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have a C++11 capable compiler you can be more specific and use "enum Class" which will force you to qualify enumerations (i.e. Race::None). ([Live demo](http://ideone.com/QfOkXd))

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Race { None, Living, Dead, Nature}; // always but invalid as the 0 entry.

class Player
{
      uint32_t m_karma;
      bool     m_myTurn;
      Race     m_myRace;

public:
    void addPlayer(int x_)
    {
        std::cout << "added player " << x_ << std::endl;
        m_karma = 0;
        m_myTurn = false;
        m_myRace = Race::None;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Player fred;
    fred.addPlayer(1);

    return 0;
}
```

"player[x].race = None" won't work because that is assignment, not a test for equality. You don't say why it didn't work, I'm going to assume - if it wasn't just the wrong variable name - because it was private or inaccessible. In that case, just add a member function to return the race:

```
class Player {
...
public:
    Race getRace() const { return m_myRace; }
    ...
};
```

Comment: ok after going threw this , everything compiles but when i do the getRace()  it returns a huge - number.  Alli have done is datapie=player[x].getRace();   cout<<datapie;

Comment: never mind,  figured it out this was correct, i had another issue thansk!

Answer (score 3):

This should work: `myRace = None;` and it's the recommended way to use an enum to avoid another mistake that you made, 4 is not a valid integer option for your enum, because Living is 0 and None will be 3.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of enums is to do away with magical numbers, so although enums are convertible to integers, getting enums from integers is counter productive.
You should write `myRace=None`, rather than `myRace=4`.

Secondly unless, you explicitly specify otherwise in your declaration of your enum type, enums starts at 0, so `None` corresponds to 3 rather than 4.

Thirdly, in C++ you don't have to write this->member_name to access a member variable. If you want to differentiate members from nonmembers, you can save many keystrokes by adopting a much shorter naming convention. (Such as appending _ to member variable names).

Finaly, `=` in C++ means **assignment**, NOT **equality comparison**. 
`if (player[x].myRace=None)` effectively means `player[x].myRace=None; if (player[x].myRace)`, i.e. the condition is always true, since *player[x].myRace==None==3*. Most of the time, the assignment operator inside `if` conditions is an error and your compiler might warn you about this.

Also, it's kind of weird for a member variable to access your `myRace` global (and globals are usually a bad idea). If myRace is not a global, then a function can access it only if a pointer or a reference is passed to it as an argument or if myRace is made as a member variable and your function is a method of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful here ! myRace is not part of Player class. So you will have one instance of myRace, whatever the number of players.
You should make myRace part of your class. If you don't, everytime you create a new player, the race changes !

If this is what you want, it should be a static member of your player class, so you could add a static getter tro retrieve it

```
class Player{

    static int myRace;

public:
    static int GetMyRace(){
        return myRace;
    }
    ...
}
```

and then, access it like this :

```
Player::GetMyRace();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a non-static field? "myRace" implies the race is _mine_ (the object's), not everyone's.

Comment: That's what I am saying... it should be part of Player class if we want as many instances of myRace as Player. But I have some difficlties reading OP's mind here... If it is not part on myRace in the first place, that certainly because he does not want it ?

Comment: everytime a player is created, i want that player to have there own race.

Comment: @ValekHalfHear It's static in my code cause OP presented an example with a global var. I said it seemed a weird idea, but if it is what he wants, then this could be achieved using a static...